# Parseval's Theorem on a Random Signal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

I'm struggling with Parseval's Theorem. I'm trying to relate variation in the time domain to the average value in the frequency domain. To do this, I'm performing the Fourier Transform on an arbitary random signal that I've generated with 2048 points (although the graph below only shows 100 of them) and a standard distribution (in this particular case) of 0.58:

[image: Time domain trace of random signal - NB only showing 100 of 2048 points!]

The frequency domain, after an FFT, then looks like this:

[image: Frequency domain trace of random signal]

with an average value of 0.022 - although this depends on the number of samples used.

Now when I try to apply Parseval's Theorem, where:

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} |X[k]|^2 $

I run into a problem. When I do the summations, I get 678 for the time domain and 0.662 for the frequency domain. When I apply the factor of $1/N$ I end up with 0.0003 for the frequency side - clearly a long way off!

Obviously I'm going wrong somewhere, but can't see where. This many orders of magnitudes off isn't very encouraging...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your calculations:

> >> x = rand(2048,1) + 1j * rand(2048,1);
>
> >> sum( abs(x).^2 )
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>       1348.28864693858
> ```
>
> >> sum( abs(fft(x)).^2 ) / 2048
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>       1348.28864693858
> ```